# twitter returning decoded json

Tags: php, twitter

Well things have been going well so far i viewed all of the information regarding a specific hashtag such as #jb, I viewed it correctly and saw a load of different arrays with specific elements such as "created_at" etc.

I have tried to target a specific element by doing this `echo $decode[0]['created_at']."<br>";`
But it gave me an error "Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\hashtag.php on line 6" - I thought i was going along the right lines untill this, any guidance would be appreciated

Charecteristics regarding the array can be viewed here [http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23jb](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#jb)

Regards

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23jb", true); //getting the file content
$decode = json_decode($json, true); //getting the file content as array

echo "<pre>";
echo $decode[0]['created_at']."<br>"; //user location
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($decode)` - what does the array look like?

Comment: Better yet, why don't you echo out $json to find out what they actually sent back to you. When I clicked that link I got "{"error":"You must enter a query."}". That means you ought to be checking for an error before trying to use that data.

Comment: its wierd but the direct link does not work, if you copy and paste the link into your browser you can see the json information - and when i used var_dump it displayed all information regarding the json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo $decode['results'][0]['created_at']."<br>"; //user location
echo "</pre>";
```

I think. But `created_at` doesn't return location - it returns date.

Comment: `var_dump()` isn't only related to JSON. Generally, when you are unsure about a variable, you should always `var_dump()` it to see what is assigned to it. Most of the times you'll find wrapping `var_dump()` around `pre` tags really helpful, too.